# ConEmu - Windows Explorer: Make "Con Emu Here" open in existing ConEmu Window

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, conemu

I have ConEmu, Windows Explorer, folder right click, "Con Emu Here" working, however the folder always opens in a new ConEmu Application. I would like the folder to open as a new tab within an existing ConEmu Application. I have the following settings:

- Menu Item: ConEmu Here
- Command: `{cmd} -cur_console:n -reuse -run "shell"`
- Icon File: `C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe,0`

I pressed the "Register" button after making those changes, I have restarted ConEmu and removed old versions.

Versions:

- Windows 7
- ConEmu: 160609 64 Stable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](http://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsIntegration.html#Command):

> Want to run shell in the existing window instead of creating new one? Use `/single` switch with following `/cmd`

So I entered the following text, and pressed <kbd>Register</kbd>, and it worked.

```
/single /cmd {cmd} -cur_console:n
```

**Screenshot:** (ConEmu changed the command after saving/registering)

[image: The working ConEmu configuration]

Answer (score 0):

> Command: {cmd} -cur_console:n -reuse -run "shell"

Awful. With that command you tell:

Run cmd.exe (the task) with parameters `-reuse -run "shell"`. Of course, cmd.exe does not support these switches.

[Docs page](http://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsIntegration.html) tells you that ConEmu switches have to be specific **before** shell command. Specifying them inside out is absolutely illogical.

Moreover. You ask ConEmu about `{cmd}` task **and**  tells to run `shell`. What? How ConEmu would decide what to run? Illogical. What is the "shell" at last? Did you write your own command line interpreter "shell.exe"? I doubt.

The following is logical and working. Why it's so hard?

```
-reuse -run {cmd} -cur_console:n
```

Comment: Full disclosure - [Maximus](http://onemansblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/inconceivable.jpg) is the author of ConEmu.

> Why it's so hard?

@MattG - I'd suggest providing some feedback - there's obviously a gap between your understanding and the ConEmu documentation...

Comment: Maximus, thanks for a great application! Just some feedback - the tooltip for the `Command:` input, says: `Use '-resuse -run "shell"' to reuse the existing ConEmu window instead of creating a new one`. This is misleading, doesn't work, and [contradicts the documentation](http://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsIntegration.html#Command). You might want to update it. Also, `-reuse -run {cmd} -cur_console:n` doesn't work, and gives the following error message `'-reuse' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.

Comment: 1. Don't use old builds. 2. Replace "shell" with your actual shell command. These must be obvious.

Comment: Is 22 hours old? I'm using [ConEmuSetup.160612.exe](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/releases/tag/v16.06.12)

Comment: It's actual. Note about old builds is the first thing to check. Actually, it would be nice if you can suggest text of hint which would be more clear.

Comment: Sure... it's a bit wordy, but how about the following text (with "more details" link) >> Use the '/single' switch to reuse the existing ConEmu window instead of creating a new one. E.g. for windows ‘/single -run {cmd} –cur_console:n'. [More details...](http://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsIntegration.html#Command) </>